# PHP image functions that were working are now yielding all black images

Tags: php, image, gd

I have used this same code for years with zero issues.  Recently, my client's server was upgraded from PHP 5 to PHP 7, which broke a host of items.  I had thought that all of this was resolved, but this one still persists.

Here is my function.

```
function imageupload($filearray, $maxsize=0, $itemid=0){
    $validtype=1;
    $avalidtype=0;


$randfilename=sha1(microtime().rand(0,99999));

global $uploadDir;
global $dbh;


$fileid=0;
if ( (is_uploaded_file($filearray['tmp_name'])) && ($validtype==1)) {
    $src=$filearray['name'];
        $randfilename.=".jpg";
    $file_name = $uploadDir . $randfilename;
$file_name = stripslashes($file_name);
$file_name = str_replace("'","",$file_name);
    copy($filearray['tmp_name'],$file_name);

    if(preg_match('.jpeg',$src)||preg_match('.jpg',$src)) {
        $src=imagecreatefromjpeg($filearray['tmp_name']);
    }
    elseif(preg_match('.png',$src)) {   
    $src = imagecreatefrompng($filearray['tmp_name']);   
    }  

    $src2=$file_name;
    list($width,$height)=getimagesize($src2);

    $thumbsize=getThumbSize($width, $height, 450);
    $newwidth=$thumbsize[0];
    $newheight=$thumbsize[1];
    $awidth=$width;
    $aheight=$height;
    $new_name = $uploadDir .  $randfilename;
    $tmp= imagecreatetruecolor($newwidth,$newheight)
    or croak("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
    //  list($twidth,$theight)=getimagesize($tmp);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp,$src,0,0,0,0,$newwidth,$newheight,$width,$height); 
    imagejpeg($tmp,$new_name,100);
    imagedestroy($tmp);

}//end function
```

I have validated that the filearray being passed is populated with legitimate data.  I have validated that the resize function is working properly.  I have validated that the subfolder where the resized images are to be saved does have proper permissions (I've even set it and the parent folder to 777).

It doesn't matter if I upload a jpeg or a png, I still get blank black boxes (of the correct dimensions).  This worked flawlessly in PHP 5 - and in fact works on multiple other servers.

What obvious thing am I missing?

Comment: When doing the php upgrade, was the GD library also upgraded?

Comment: The web host did the upgrade across the board.  I'm not saying that they didn't miss this, but it seems unlikely.  I'll do a phpinfo and see if that sheds any light.

Comment: No luck there.  

PHP version 7.3.14
GD bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
It all seems in order.